# Yup conditional validation when field is equal to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I need a schema like this:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
SKU: yup.string().required(),
name: yup.string().required(),
price: yup.number().required(),
type: yup.string().required(),
size: yup
  .number()
  .moreThan(0)
  .when('type', {
    is: (type) => type === 'DVD',
    then: yup.number().moreThan(0).required(),
  }),
height: yup
  .number()
  .moreThan(0)
  .when('type', {
    is: (type) => type === 'furniture',
    then: yup.number().moreThan(0).required(),
  }),
width: yup
  .number()
  .moreThan(0)
  .when('type', {
    is: (type) => type === 'furniture',
    then: yup.number().moreThan(0).required(),
  }),
length: yup
  .number()
  .moreThan(0)
  .when('type', {
    is: (type) => type === 'furniture',
    then: yup.number().moreThan(0).required(),
  }),
weight: yup
  .number()
  .moreThan(0)
  .when('type', {
    is: (type) => type === 'book',
    then: yup.number().moreThan(0).required(),
  }),
});
```

When field type is equal to "DVD" I would like to make the size field required etc.
but the parts `is: (type) => type === 'DVD'` etc throw a warning:

> Warning: An unhandled error was caught during validation in  TypeError: branch is not a function

My form looks like this:

```
        <Formik
        validationSchema={schema}
        validateOnChange={false}
        validateOnBlur={false}
        onSubmit={console.log}
        initialValues={{
          SKU: '',
          name: '',
          price: 0,
          type: 'DVD',
          size: 1,
          height: 1,
          width: 1,
          length: 1,
          weight: 1,
        }}
      >
        ...
      </Formik>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: It seems work. Can you provide the form data you put into the validation schema?